# Having Trouble finding the correct scope for my API request to Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

This is likely just a matter of me not knowing how to find the correct scope but I need help all the same.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import requests
import pprint
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

forcewinds_folder_url = 'fake-folder-url'

load_dotenv()
api_key = os.getenv('JAKE_KEY')
json_key_location = os.getenv('API_KEY_JSON_PATH')
# Replace 'YOUR_JSON_FILE.json' with the path to your downloaded JSON credentials file
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(json_key_location, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly'])

# Create a Google Drive API service
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

folder_name = 'fake-folder-id'

results = drive_service.files().list(q=f"name = '{folder_name}' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute()
folders = results.get('files', [])

# Check if the folder was found and retrieve its ID
if folders:
    folder_id = folders[0]['id']
    print(f"The folder ID for '{folder_name}' is: {folder_id}")
else:
    print(f"No folder found with the name '{folder_name}'")
```

This code is giving me this error

```
File "get_txt.py", line 21, in <module>
    results = drive_service.files().list(q=f"name = '{folder_name}' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute()
  File "/home/zoctavous/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zoctavous/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name+%3D+%271RyT2IS-dhGLCNcod_LVt246463PBR3bH%27+and+mimeType+%3D+%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27&alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">
```

Which indicates a permissions issue. I have a json for the credentials of my project that has Google Drive API enabled here
[image]

I've made sure I've updated my authentication json every time I add permissions to that account and I've given it everything that seems to make sense to me to access a google drive folder on my account. Im fairly sure that I am authenticating and creating my credentials correctly so im fairly stuck.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in your showing script, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly` is used as the scope. But, in your script, you are trying to use Drive API. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`. In this case, please modify the scope. Please select the scope you want to use from the following scopes.

If you use only "Method: files.list of Drive API v3", you can use the following scope.

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly`

or, if you want to retrieve the file content, please use the following scope.

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`

or, if you want to retrieve and update the files, please use the following scope.

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

#### References:

- [Method: files.list of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list)
- [Scopes for Method: files.list of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list#authorization-scopes)

Comment: Ill give this a try! - I hope I just needed to learn about what scope to use to make this work. Trying in the morning :)

Comment: in the future - if I have a specific function that Im interested in using where in the Google Documentation can I find that corresponding scope that my credentials should encompass?

Comment: @Syllogism Thank you for replying. About your additional question of `if I have a specific function that Im interested in using where in the Google Documentation can I find that corresponding scope that my credentials should encompass?`, in this case, I think that you can see the scopes of the official document of the API. For example, when it's "Method: files.list of Drive API v3", you can see the scopes at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list#authorization-scopes .

Comment: @Syllogism Or, when you want to see all scopes of Google APIs, I think that this official document https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes might be useful.

Comment: This wound up being not the whole answer - but it set me on the right path. Thank you sir!